# how to use setters and getters in methods

Tags: java

I have to write a Resistor class. When a Resistor object is first instantiated, its default resistance is 1 ohm, and its default type is "film". This is all I have

```
public class Resistor{
private int resistance;
private int type;

public Resistor(int r) {
    resistance = r;
}

public int getResistance() {
    return resistance;
}

public double getType() {
    return type;

}
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If the default value for `type` is supposed to be `"film"`, then "film" should almost certainly be a string rather than an int.

Comment: Just use an enum rather than an int or String. But yeah not sure what the question is exactly.

Answer (score 1):

first, `type` is not an `int` datatype, its `String`:

your constructor should looks like this since it has default value

```
public Resistor() {
    resistance = 1;
    type = "film";
}
```

for setter,

```
public void setResistance(int r){
  resistance = r;
}

public void setType(String t){
  type = t;
}
```

Comment: It almost certainly should be an `enum`, not a `String`.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to define setters for type and resistance.

```
public void setResistance(int resistance) {
    this.reistance = resistance;
}

public void setType(double type) {
    this.type = type;
}
```

> How to use setter/getter method"?

=> You can create an object of the class and can assign values using setter method, and whenever you require the value from object you can use getter method.

For example:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setResistance(2);
foo.setType(2.2);
```

Comment: This is a really incomplete answer.  He also forgot a setter for `resistance`, left `type` out of the constructor, didn't include a default constructor which his requirements clearly ask for...